# NOTE: The query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data message in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

When I run the proc sql sas code below, my program keep running and it does not stop. The note says  The query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data message in SAS
Does anybody know why it keep doing this?

Here is my code:

```
proc sql;
create table PUBLIC.ILK_ODENEN_SAYI as
SELECT* FROM
    (select datepart(i1.UpdatedDate) as date FORMAT DATE9.,
    COUNT(*) AS ILK_ODENEN_SAYI,
    sum(InvoiceAmount) as ILK_ODENEN_MIKTAR
    from fatura.ASKIDAFATURA_INVOICES as i1
    where i1.Status=2 and i1.CorparateIdentity in (1,2) and
    (select count(*) 
    from fatura.ASKIDAFATURA_INVOICES  as i2
    where i2.Status=2 and i2.CorparateIdentity in (1,2) AND 
    i1.CitizenIdentity=i2.CitizenIdentity and i2.UpdatedDate < i1.UpdatedDate
    )=0
    /*GROUP BY i1.UpdatedDate*/
    ) tt;
quit;
```

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Hey, do not deface your question. It isn't fair to the site and it isn't allowed. If you re-do this, the moderators will be forced to lock your question. Let's avoid this.

Comment: Sorry, it was unintentional

Answer (score 5):

Your query is grouping by `i1.UpdatedDate` rather than the calculated date column you are creating from `il1.UpdatedDate`. To remove this message, group by `calculated date` instead. Your query is asking for `datepart(il1.UpdatedDate)`, not `il1.UpdatedDate`.

In other words, your rows may not be collapsing down to a single date if `UpdatedDate` is a timestamp that is not aligned (e.g. `01JAN2020:00:00`, `02JAN2020:00:00`, etc.).

For more information on this message, see [SAS Usage Note 4308](https://support.sas.com/techsup/notes/v8/4/308.html).

**Details**

This is actually a really neat feature of SAS and saves a lot of time in coding. Let's explore why this message occurs with a very simple example. Suppose we want to calculate the average horsepower per make in sashelp.cars:

```
proc sql;
    create table avg_make_horsepower as
        select make, mean(horsepower) as avg_horsepower
        from sashelp.cars
        group by make
    ;
quit;
```

We get this table:

```
Make        avg_horsepower
Acura       239.28571429
Audi        250.78947368
BMW         241.45
Buick       214.44444444
Cadillac    298.125
...
```

Now suppose we want to compare every model's horsepower to the average horsepower by their make. This means we need to bring in two columns, `model` and `horsepower`. But, we don't want to group by `make`, `model`, and `horsepower` together. In other flavors of SQL, you would calculate this with a subquery and a join:

```
proc sql;
    create table avg_horsepower_make_vs_model as
        select t1.make
             , t1.model
             , t1.horsepower
             , t2.avg_make_horsepower
        from sashelp.cars as t1
        LEFT JOIN
             (select make, mean(horsepower) as avg_make_horsepower
              from sashelp.cars
              group by make
             ) as t2
        ON t1.make = t2.make
    ;
quit;
```

Which gives us this:

```
Make    Model            Horsepower    avg_make_horsepower
Acura   MDX              265           239.28571429
Acura   RSX Type S 2dr   200           239.28571429
Acura   TSX 4dr          200           239.28571429
Acura   TL 4dr           270           239.28571429
Acura   3.5 RL 4dr       225           239.28571429
...
```

But in SAS, you don't have to do this. All you need to do is specify the columns that you want in your final table and specify what you want to group by. We can get the exact same results with this query:

```
proc sql;
    create table avg_horsepower_make_vs_model as
        select make
             , model
             , horsepower
             , mean(horsepower) as avg_make_horsepower
        from sashelp.cars 
        group by make
    ;
quit;
```

You'll see this message in the log:

```
NOTE: The query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data.
```

SAS is doing this join for you automatically in the background. It's calculating the average of horsepower by `make`, then joining it back by `make` to the table with `make`, `model`, and `horsepower`. In other words, it's doing two steps:

1. Calculate the average `horsepower` by `make`
2. Query `make`, `model`, `horsepower` and join it with (1) by `make`

This same feature is also true if you're creating calculated columns. For example:

```
proc sql;
    create table foo as
        select datepart(timestamp) as date
             , count(*) as total
        from have
        group by timestamp
    ;
quit;
```

Timestamp is not a column that will result from the query. SAS will (1) calculate `count(*)` by `timestamp`, then (2) merge it back with `datepart(timestamp)`. To fix this, group by `calculated date` instead.

```
proc sql;
    create table foo as
        select datepart(timestamp) as date
             , count(*) as total
        from have
        group by calculated date
    ;
quit;
```

`calculated date` is a shortcut that lets SAS know you want to group by the calculated column `date` in your query. You do not need to rewrite `datepart(timestamp)` in the `group by`.