# I need to add a new column test4 from test3 where test2 has a value 0. in SAS?

Tags: sas

Input

```
Tl  LineNo Amnt_pd
01      0     .
01      1     93
01      2     0
01      3     25
01      4      0
02      0     40
02      1     0
```

Output

```
Tl  LineNo Amnt_pd  Amt_H
01      1     93    118
01      2     0     118
01      3     25    118
01      4     0     118
02      1     0      40
```

If the line no is zero for tl and amntpaid has value than keep the amntpaid value itself for rest of the rows of lineno. If lineno is zero and missing(.) then sum up the values for all other line no and fill the same sum amount for rest of the rows of Lineno for the new var Amnt_H. I need to code this in SAS. Anyhelp is appreciated?

Comment: Here are two ways to try. 1) Merge Proc means by Tl output with original data. 2) use Proc SQL selecting sum of amount paid groupign by Tl.

Comment: I did the same but didn't know a way to get rid of lineno="0".

I first did proc sql and got the sum amount for all tl. I merged the sum amount table with original table. 

I had something like this,
merge test4 test5
if Lineno eq "0" and not missing (amnt_pd) then do;
   Amnt_H=Amnt_pd;
end;
if Lineno eq "0" and missing (amnt_pd) then do;
   Amnt_H=Amnt_PD_SUM;
 end;
run;

I also do not have a sorted Lineno which throws error it is not sorted properly? any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75554454/how-to-calculate-mean-values-per-values-in-other-column-in-one-proc-sql-query-in/75554700#75554700).

One way using a DoW Loop

```
proc sort data=have; by Tl; run;

data want;
    do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.Tl);
        set have;
        by Tl;
        Amt_H=sum(Amt_H, amnt_pd);
    end;

    do until (last.Tl);
        set have;
        by Tl;
        if LineNo ne 0 then output;
    end;
run;
```

```
Tl LineNo Amnt_pd Amt_H
01    1     93     118
01    2      0     118
01    3     25     118
01    4      0     118
02    1      0      40
```

Comment: Thank you so much! the above logic worked

Comment: This is straight by-group magic! Awesome solution!